# SELECT where row value contains string MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select a row in my MySQL DB where the value of a column contains 'XcodeDev' for example?

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username LIKE '$query'
```

But it only selects a row were the Username value is exactly the same to the query.

What can I do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use the [`%` wildcard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), which matches any number of characters.

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username LIKE '%query%'
```

Comment: I think you are missing the doller sign

Comment: very useful +1.

Answer (score 18):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username LIKE '%$query%'
```

Comment: This is used to denote variable names in PHP.

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion would be

```
$value = $_POST["myfield"];

$Query = Database::Prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MYFIELD LIKE ?");
$Query->Execute(array("%".$value."%"));
```

Comment: Hello @Marcelo what can use instead of  Database class in the prepare statement? There was a compile error for the Database class.

Comment: @ThePredator ^^

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username LIKE '%$query%'
```

but it's not suggested. use PDO